# Win32_EncryptableVolume to get bitlocker status in C#

Tags: c#, wmi, status

In c# I'm using the following code the get the status of BitLocker. 
When i run the script is says: Management Exception was unhandled.
Any ideas?

> ```
> ManagementClass objectSearcher;
>             List<string> BitLocker = new List<string>();
>
>             objectSearcher = new ManagementClass("Win32_EncryptableVolume");
>             foreach (var item in objectSearcher.GetInstances())
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                  BitLocker.Add(item["DeviceID"].ToString());
>                  BitLocker.Add(item["ProtectionStatus"].ToString());
>
>                 }
>                 catch
>                 {
>                     BitLocker.Add("Error, could not retrieve data. \n");
>                 }
>
>             }
> ```
>
> [image: Image1]

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need to set a path and scope first, for example:

```
var path = new ManagementPath(@"\ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftVolumeEncryption") { ClassName = "Win32_EncryptableVolume" };
var scope = new ManagementScope(path);
path.Server = Environment.MachineName;
var objectSearcher = new ManagementClass(scope, path, new ObjectGetOptions());
```

Comment: this mght just be it!